# SHAREPOINT 2007 LLISTS created by helpdesk.wsp

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I am given a task to make a feature that autogenerates a ticket ID for a list.
However, I found out that the template used for the site is a helpdesk.wsp template.
Now, I am having problems stapling the said feature to Service Requests because it is currently under LLISTS and not LISTS.

See attached image.[image]

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks.
janejanejane

Comment: i can access Service Requests. however, when i try to access it through code, it seems that the custom Feature is not called.

Comment: the url is ..helpdesk2/LLists/Service%20Requests/AllItems.aspx

Comment: You need to provide more details. Is your feature correctly activated? Did you try to attach the debugger and debug the `FeatureActivated` method? Did you check the logs (SharePoint ones and Windows ones)?

Comment: sadly, the feature does not attach to the list (servicerequest). 
i have created a custom list (test) with the required columns and it has updated the said columns. 
when i saved the servicerequest as a template and created this template as another list (servicerequest2), it still didn't attach to the list.

im confused to the behavior. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by just adding my newly created column to the default Content Type which is "Service Request". Weird. But it behaves accordingly now.